# <asp:File upload control is not visible what ever I do

Tags: asp.net

Some thing weird is happening. I created a simple form and Added an `<asp:file upload>` control to the page. When I run it, I am not able to see the control at all.

When I click on the place where  I added it is letting me upload a file. I even added visible="true" still not able to see the control.

When I click on the page source I see something suspicious that may be the reason for the forms behavior.

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" 
        value="/wEWAwKLs+6YAwLCi9reAwKgt7D9ClxerRe75aEgGdz92Sy7arcrPod6Ll9TW47l0BpDRTNL" />
```

Did you ever experience this? Can youy tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="filResume" class="file" 
        runat="server" width="600" size="81" />
</div>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqFilResume" 
        ControlToValidate="filResume" 
        Display="Dynamic"
        cssClass="validator_right">*Required
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    Display="Dynamic" 
    id="fileUploadValidator" 
    runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="*Resume must be a .pdf, .doc, or .docx file!" 
    ValidationExpression="^.+\.(pdf|PDF|doc|DOC|docx|DOCX)$" 
    ControlToValidate="filResume"
    cssClass="validator_right">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: What CSS is applied to the `file` class? You say if you click "where it is" that it works - you just can't see it. The `Control.Visible` property would not cause that if it were set to false: it wouldn't be on the page markup at all.

Comment: input[type=file] {
 position: relative;
 text-align: right;
 -moz-opacity:0 ;
 filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 2;
}
div.fileinputs 
{
    float:left;
    width:610px;
 position: relative;
}

Comment: __EVENTVALIDATION is autogenerated by webforms. are your controls rendered within the `asp:Form` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS is the problem. You are setting it to be completely transparent.

```
input[type=file] {
   position: relative; 
   text-align: right; 
   -moz-opacity:0 ; 
   filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
   opacity: 0;
```

Set those `opacity` numbers to something above 0. (The filter:alpha goes on a scale of 0-100; the others are 0-10, I believe)